# OpenKinect: Compile custom code on MAC

Tags: kinect

Can someone please tell me how to compile custom kinect code on MAC.
I have downloaded and built the OpenKinect as instructed by the guide(and yes glview works fine)

I am following this: http://openkinect.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_GL_Example

But I am not able to produce any output file.

```
g++ -g -Wall `pkg-config --cflags libfreenect` -lopengl32 -lglut32  `pkg-config --libs libfreenect` -lGL -lGLU -lglut  -c main.cpp
Package libfreenect was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libfreenect.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libfreenect' found
Package libfreenect was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libfreenect.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libfreenect' found
In file included from main.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/libfreenect.hpp:29:25: error: libfreenect.h: No such file or directory
In file included from main.cpp:27:
/usr/local/include/libfreenect.hpp:46: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
```